# bindValue error: Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\eindwerk6\classes\User.php on line 362

Tags: php, arrays, pdo, data-binding, prepared-statement

I have been busy with a follow function. However, "**Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\eindwerk6\classes\User.php**" on line 364 keeps popping up.

This is the relevant function in User.php:

```
public function checkFollow($mainID, $guest){
    $conn = db::getInstance();

    $statement = $conn -> prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM followOthers WHERE followerID=:followerID AND followingID=:followingID");
    $statement -> bindValue(':followerID', $mainID); //this is line 364      
    $statement -> bindValue(':followingID', $guest);
    return $statement;
}
```

This is where I call to that function:

```
$check = $user->checkFollow($currentUser, $guest);
$countCheck = 0;
foreach ($check as $c){
    $countCheck = 0;
}
```

This is where it's supposed to be used:

```
if($check->fetchColumn() == 1){
    echo "<a class='btn btn-default' href='#'>Unfollow</a>";
}else{
    echo  "<a class='btn btn-default' href='#'>Follow</a>";
}
```

Comment: Is `$currentUser` an array?

Comment: Problem solved. Just had to change $currentUser to $mainID.